# Check if a program exists and if not to install it

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, nsis

I am writing a Jenkins build with an NSIS file. I need a script to check if the device has a certain program installed on it and if it doesn't, it should install the .exe's from the installer folder. I have all the .exe's in the install folder required for the installer to work.

This should be rather simple but i am baffled in this case and could not find any information about this anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are using a windows environment. You could write a powershell script to check it:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName | Select-String 'Microsoft Visual C\+\+'
```

This will list all installed Visual C++ Redistributables

On my machine it looks like that:

```
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64)}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 Additional Runtime - 11.0.61030}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.30729.6161}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64)}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.30729.17}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Additional Runtime - 12.0.21005}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2013  x64 Designtime - 12.0.21005}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Debug Runtime - 14.0.23506}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Minimum Runtime - 14.0.23506}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Minimum Runtime - 12.0.21005}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 Debug Runtime - 11.0.60610}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64)}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Additional Runtime - 14.0.23506}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Debug Runtime - 12.0.21005}
@{DisplayName=Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 Minimum Runtime - 11.0.61030}
```

So if your program you want to check is called `ProgramWithName` just use:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName | Select-String ProgramWithName
```

If you want to know if the SQL Server is installed use:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName | Select-String 'Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express'
```

this gives you on my machine:

```
@{DisplayName=Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB }
```

Comment: But what if i want the script to check if SQL is installed and if not i want the script to run the .exe in the folder ? but this answer will surely work for the other .exe's i have. Thank you